# An example of xml processing but using anti-xml instead of Scala xml

Tags: scala, anti-xml

I'd like to see a rewrite of bellow script using http://anti-xml.org instead of Scala XML.

This is an excerpt from Chapter 10. Herding XML in Scala - http://ofps.oreilly.com/titles/9780596155957/HerdingXMLInScalaDSLs.html

```
// code-examples/XML/reading/pattern-matching-script.scala
import scala.xml._
val someXML =
 <sammich>
   <bread>wheat</bread>
   <meat>salami</meat>
   <condiments>
     <condiment expired="true">mayo</condiment>
     <condiment expired="false">mustard</condiment>
   </condiments>
</sammich>

someXML match {
 case <sammich>{ingredients @ _*}</sammich> => {
    for (cond @ <condiments>{_*}</condiments> <- ingredients)
      println("condiments: " + cond.text)
    }
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 6):

I'm not familiar with antixml, however, as there is no other answer, I'll make a try

Just for the record, your code returns

```
  mayo
  mustard
```

More precisely, the string starts with the blanks/newline between the end of  and the start of the first . The blanks between mayo and mustard are the ones between the two condiment, and the blanks after mustard is the one before the closing .

In antixml, first thing to do seems to convert your, which is simply

```
val someAntiXml = someXML.anti
```

Getting the condiments part is easy :

```
var condiments = someAntiXml \ 'condiments
```

Then one has to extract the text. It sounded like the way to do this was

```
condiments \\ text
```

But `\\` does not traverse the structure in order, it looks like breadth-first traversal. As a consequence, the blanks, which are just under condiments, comes before mayo and mustard, which are one level below, in the  elements.

So here is a possible implementation to retrieve the text. Maybe there is a more standard way, but I did not find one.

```
def textOf(g: Group[Node]) : String = 
  g.toList.map{
    case Elem(_, _, _, _, children) => textOf(children) 
    case t: Text => t.text
    case c: CDATA => c.text 
    case _ => ""
  }.mkString
```

Then `textOf(someAntiXml \ "condiments")` gives the expected result.

Comment: In anti-xml 0.3 and later, [\\ does traverse in depth-first order](https://github.com/djspiewak/anti-xml/issues/49), so `condiments \\ text` now works fine.